# Why does the "zoom" property not work in pdf via Adobe Acrobat JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

According to the [Acrobat JavaScript Scripting Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acro6JS.pdf) the zoom property of a pdf document can be set like so: `this.zoom = 100;` However, running this script in a form button doesn't change anything while running the same document in another pdf program (Bluebeam Revu) yields expected results. The property isn't restricted or require heightened permissions (according to the documentation). Has anyone had success in getting this to work in Adobe?

Comment: Not all PDF viewers execute JavaScript in the same way as Acrobat.

Comment: @joelgeraci I know. I'm wondering why a script in Adobe's scripting reference doesn't work in Adobe.

Comment: It works for me. See the sample file here https://www.dropbox.com/s/kswec8h7xbflqeg/bodea-summary-zoom-button.pdf?dl=1